# Django edit form not showing the previosly entered data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    profile, created = ProfileGroom.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('profiles:profile', username=request.user.username)
context = {
    "title": 'Edit Profile',
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, 'profiles/profile_form.html', context)
```

profile_form.html

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url "profiles:profile_update" %}' 

enctype='multipart/form-data' role="form">{% csrf_token %}

<div id="div_id_first_name" class="form-group"> <label for="id_first_name" class="control-label ">
                        First name
</label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_first_name" maxlength="80" name="first_name" type="text" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_last_name" class="form-group"> <label for="id_last_name" class="control-label ">
                        Last name
</label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" type="text" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_age" class="form-group"> <label for="id_age" class="control-label ">
                        Age
</label> <div class="controls "> <input class="numberinput form-control" id="id_age" name="age" type="number" /> 

<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Add/Edit Profile' />
</form>
```

Form is saving data and working but when open for editing the data, it doesn't retain previously entered data. Any body can help? Thank you.

Comment: You've hard coded almost the entire form html... how is it supposed to show the data?

Comment: I can write just {{ form.as_p }}, but need to write this way to integrate jquery. It saves the entered data, but only the problem is for editing all fields shows blank

Comment: The documentation shows there are ways of [rendering form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)...

Comment: That works. Thank you so much...